# Replication in same server within different databases. Mysql 5.6

Tags: mysql, replication, windows, mysql-5.6, mysqladmin

What I have :

- a windows machine with one instance of MySQL 5.6 Server.
- two database named test and test2.
- `Test` database has a table called `activity` with columns `id` and `class`

What I need :

- replication of `test.activity` table to `test2` database with a condition that `Test.activity.class = 'B'`.

I know how to replicate with in different server. But not for same server within different database.I have checked [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6375320/mysql-replication-on-single-server) , but it does not give enough information.

Comment: That wouldn't be a normal situation at all! You can't alter the database during replication, and the master / slave cannot have the same server ids. I'd recommend if you must do this, then set up some triggers on the first DB, to replicate the insert / update commands against the second one.

Comment: Setup `test2.activity` as a view to `test.activity` with condition?

Comment: @TanHongTat and then ??\

Comment: I assume you need the replication to keep the data in sync, so, instead of setting up a replication, you can simply setup a view to the original table.

Comment: but i want replication in another database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That wouldn't be a normal situation at all! You can't alter the database during replication, and the master / slave cannot have the same server ids. I'd recommend if you must do this, then set up some triggers on the first DB, to replicate the insert / update commands against the second one.

Comment: isnt it possible in same way as we have in SQL-SERVER for distributor/publisher

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.

Answer (score 1):

If i did understand correctly your need, You can have 2 MySQL instances on one single server (OS) then you could configure one of them as Master and another as Slave. You must create different my.conf,we named it my1.conf and my2.conf that each one should be different on port number and socket path and log error path and some other parameters. With this approach, you will run 2 MySQL daemon with different configurations. For complete doc please go to https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/multiple-servers.html .

Comment: i have only one mysql 5.6 instance on my system

Comment: Ok. you can install another one with different configuration file that will be up another MySQL instance on separate port number and other attributes.  Unless I do not know another approach.

Comment: nima0102 - i have to check for the another installation.

Comment: Yes. You can have 2 or more MySQL instance with different configuration. Of course, if your intention is just only for experimental, I do suggest visualization software to do your tests. Installation easily separate OS and then deploy MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Cause it's on the same server, why don't you use a trigger for this?

If you just wanna replicate data you can add a triger on update or on insert or both whatever you need. This way you can use your condition easily. Master/Slave replication would be better for different servers.

You can look [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/trigger-syntax.html) for mysql Trigger examples.
And [here](http://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/triggers/after_insert.php) is a sample for your case.

Comment: Trigger is not my solution

Answer (score 0):

Try mysql sandbox, it will probably solve your issue (http://mysqlsandbox.net/)

Answer (score 0):

Because:

> replication of test.activity table to test2 database with a condition
>   that Test.activity.class = 'B'.

Native replication not help, and in this case better to leave both database on same server and just install trigger for INSER/UPDATE/DELETE on Master database, which will check conditions and make direct changes on second database.

This is simplest way. There are many other possible.